# how to run c code with simplescalar?

Tags: c, simulation, branch-prediction

I want to simulate perceptron branch predictor with `simplescalar`. I write a simple code in c programming language. In `simplescalar` installation guide this command will compile c code:

```
$ $IDIR/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-gcc –o hello hello.c
```

but I don't have bin directory. I modified it to this command:

```
$ $IDIR/sslittle-na-sstrix-gcc –o hello hello.c
```

again the problem is that there is no `sslittle-na-sstrix-gcc` directory. I don't know what I should do??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

sslittle-na-sstrix-gcc is NOT A DIRECTORY.

You should look for some tutorials on how to properly install SimpleScalar:

[SimpleScalar Installation Guide](http://www.ann.ece.ufl.edu/courses/eel5764_10fal/project/simplescalar_installation.pdf)